# LINQ query with multi-threading

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, linq

I have a multi-threading app where several threads manipulate a list (Of T), add, remove, and query the list. Here one of the threads query the list and then need to iterate the result set. Of course it's expected to get an exception indicates a collection was changed during the iteration, for some reason related the nature of the query and the iteration behavior I can't lock the list here, so I tried to get a copy of the result using the .ToList() function, but it was strange that I still receive the same error. I thought .ToList() function get separated list of the result, but it not looks to be. Is there any alternative way to get the query result in a new list?

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe.  You can't do that.

Comment: DO you get the exception in the call to `ToList`, or when you're iterating over the result?

Comment: @SLaks - Yes I know it's not thread-safe, but I need a solution to get the *result* of the query's moment in a separated list, similar to what .ToList() function do, but in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: @Jim - the exception raise during the iteration over the result of the .ToList() function

Comment: What is preventing you from using any type of concurrency?

Comment: You could try using `ToArray`, which uses a different technique to create the copy. If you need it to be a List you can use `new List(yourList.ToArray());`

Comment: When you need to manipulate a collection from more than one thread simultaneously, List<T> is not an option. You definitely need the primary collection to be one of the classes in System.Collections.Concurrent, like a ConcurrentBag, and then use ToList() to get the items out of the ConcurrentBag to do your iteration. That collection will not be affected by modifications made to the primary collection.

Comment: @user2920518 - I think ConcurrentBag is not sorted, and keeping the list entries in same order is important, and here I can't force sorting it each time I need to access it because the list containing tens of thousands of items and this will lead to noticeable delays, any suggestion to workaround this?

Comment: @jessehouwing - I tried ToArray() and the same issue is still present!

Comment: You can use OrderBy on a ConcurrentBag to sort the collection before calling ToList(). Try it and see if the delays are noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an instance of `List<T>` from multiple threads without synchronization, as the resulting behavior is undefined and in most cases leads to problems. You found one already.

Create some kind of `ConcurrentCollection` and synchronize all the operations you need:

```
public class ConcurrentCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> innerList = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lock (innerList)
        {
            innerList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public bool TryRemove(T item)
    {
        lock (innerList)
        {
            return innerList.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (innerList)
            {
                return this.innerList.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (innerList)
        {
            return (IEnumerator<T>) this.innerList.ToArray().GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The critical point here is that the returned enumerator enumerates over a snapshot of the list (`ToArray`) so it doesn't matter if it is modified in between.

Keep in mind, that you have to create "atomic" operations for your calling code. Let's assume from one thread you want to add an item only if the list is empty. This would be wrong:

```
if (collection.Count == 0)
{
    collection.Add(item);
}
```

Instead, add another member to the `ConcurrentCollection`...

```
public bool AddIfEmpty(T item)
{
    lock (innerList)
    {
        if (innerList.Count == 0)
        {
            innerList.Add(item);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

... and use it like this:

```
var itemWasAdded = collection.AddIfEmpty(item);
```

Comment: I guess that is a rough implementation of `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T>`. This code kind of  reinvents the wheel.

Comment: Agreed with Mephy here, what you should be using is a ConcurrentBag<T>. It is the concurrent equivalent of a List<T>. It's not called a list because no sorting can be done on a bag.

Comment: @Frank - thanks but all your functions force locking the list, and as I said I can't do this, all what I need is to get the result of the query in a new list or a new array, even if this result is only a snapshot and without locking the list.

Comment: @Mephy - Thanks. so far our system is running on framework 3.5, and this class is available only on 4.5+. But if I didn't find another solution then I will consider changing the target framework and will try it. But the question is: if ConcurrentBag is managing adding and removing items and force *implemented* lock, then will it lock the entire list while executing the query as well?! I still don't know how this will help me getting the result of the query and iterating the result snapshot while I still allowing other threads to keep working on the list.

Comment: Just to make it clear again, I need to iterate the result of the query, as iterating the snapshot at the moment of the query execution, and I don't care about what will happen to the list later by other threads.

Comment: @Abed My proposed solution works on 3.5 and doesn't lock the list while iterating it. Instead, it creates a snapshot by calling `ToArray` and then gets the enumerator for that array. This way, the locks are held as short as possible.

Comment: @Frank - how about accessing other extended methods like RemoveAll, and OrderBy?

Comment: @Abed All LINQ extension methods (like OrderBy) operate on an IEnumerable. That means, they will use the snapshot that is returned by GetEnumerator. RemoveAll will modify the list itself and should be delegated to the innerList inside a `lock` block.

Comment: ConcurrentBag<T> (and the other concurrent collections) allocate partial locks on the list, the internal structure is partitioned and a single concurrent collection can allocate multiple locks on different regions of the bag. They are optimized for random access, if all you are doing is adding to the collection from multiple threads, locking a List should be slightly faster.

Comment: So just to be clear, if I run a .find() from within a singleton on a List instance variable, would could the result get returned to the wrong user?